# Webpack module build failed, Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'

Tags: webpack, babel-loader

Error: babel-loader@8 requires Babel 7.x (the package '@babel/core'). If you'd like to use Babel 6.x ('babel-core'), you should install 'babel-loader@7'. 
I am getting an error when I try to build the webpack.config.js file.

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "create a graph out of a json object",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --entry ./main.js --output-filename ./dist/bundle.js",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}

module.exports = {
mode: 'development',
entry: './main.js',
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                {loader: 'style-loader'},
                {loader: 'css-loader'},
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use:[
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                }
            ],
            exclude: /node_modules/,

        }
    ]
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to replace

```
"babel-core": "^6.26.3"
```

with

```
"@babel/core": "^7"
```

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.
ERROR in ./main.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/elianeaimeh/Documents/elia-challenge/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js

Comment: I fixed the problem, I forgot to remove babel-preset-es2015 from devDependency after installing @babel-preset-env. Now webpack build is working properly.. and modified query: {presets: ['@babel/preset-env'} in webpack.config.js file.